# Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation where $ R:N\times N \to N $ defined as $(a,b) R (c,d)$ if and only if $ad(b+c) = bc(a+d).$

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation where $R:N\times N \to N$ defined as $(a,b) R (c,d)$ if and only if $ad(b+c) = bc(a+d).$

I have proved for reflexive and transitive but having a problem in proving for symmetric, please help, thank you.

Comment: Symmetry is significantly easier than transitivity, which you say you already did (honestly, that confuses me).  For symmetry, can you write out what both $(a,b) R (c,d)$ and $(c,d) R (a,b)$ are in terms of $=$ and $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Sorry I was just making a very silly mistake when trying to prove for symmetric. Got my mistake now, thanks.